# fire jquery mobile panel menu by clicking android native menu button using phonegap/cordova

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing a Android app using Jquery Mobile/Phonegap. I have the following code to control the phone's menu button:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Call onDeviceReady when PhoneGap is loaded.
    //
    // At this point, the document has loaded but phonegap-1.0.0.js has not.
    // When PhoneGap is loaded and talking with the native device,
    // it will call the event `deviceready`.
    // 
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Register the event listener
        document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);
    }

    // Handle the menu button
    //
    function onMenuKeyDown() {

    alert("It works");
    }

    </script>
```

and on the body tag i added:

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
```

so when I click the android native menu button, I get the alert message "It works"... and I would like to know which is the right code i need to add there to call the menu I created based on jquery mobile. Here is the code of the menu panel:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-display="overlay">

<ul data-role="listview" class="fondo">
<li data-icon="false"><a href="#menu" class="menutxt" data-transition="slide"><img class="ui-li-icon" src="./img/history.svg">Option 1</a></li>
<li data-icon="false"><a href="#menu" class="menutxt" data-transition="slide"><img class="ui-li-icon" src="./img/pizza.svg">Option 2</a></li>
<li data-icon="false"><a href="#menu" class="menutxt" data-transition="slide"><img class="ui-li-icon" src="./img/tag.svg">Option 3</a></li>
<li data-icon="false"><a href="#combina" class="menutxt" data-transition="slide"><img class="ui-li-icon" src="./img/cart.svg">Option 4</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Thank you for looking into this.. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are all the options/events/methods you can use for panels in JQM.

http://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/

**to open your panel**

```
$( "#mypanel" ).panel( "open" );
```

Comment: Hello Tasos! Thank you VERY MUCH for helping me out with this. This is exactly what I needed... I went ahead and implemented the toggle method which allows to show and hide when clicking the button. like so $( "#mypanel" ).panel( "open" );

Comment: on the above comment I meant like so $( "#mypanel" ).panel( "toggle" );